# How create websocket server on a domain or Ip address?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I created websocket server using Php Ratchet .

this is my code :

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    protected $wclient;
    // protected $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        // $this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
     $this->$wclient = new WebSocket\Client("wss://stream-testnet.bybit.com/contract/usdt/public/v3", ['timeout' => 3000]);
    $json='{"req_id": "100001", "op": "subscribe" ,"args": [
            "orderbook.1.BTCUSDT",
            "orderbook.1.ETHUSDT"
        ]}';
     $this->$wclient->text($json);      
        
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        // unset($this->users[$conn->resourceId]);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from,  $data) {
        

     $message = $this->$wclient->receive(); 
     $from->send($message);
      $message = $this->$wclient->receive(); 
     $from->send($message);  
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}

$server = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 6001);
$server->route('/', new Chat, ['*']);
$server->run();
```

i start server in this way in ubuntu terminal :

```
php filename.php
```

and i use javascript to connect :

```
var wsUri = 'ws://server_ipaddress:6001';   
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

websocket.onopen = function(ev) {
    
    websocket.send('connect');
}
```

every thing works fine on my localhost but on production environment I receive this error :

```
signal:544 WebSocket connection to 'ws://server_ipaddress:6001/' failed:
```

server listen on port 6001(127.0.0.1:6001)
this is netstat command result :

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      309797/php
```

firewall is open for port 6001
and telnet command on ubuntu terminal can connect to 127.0.0.1:6001

I also tested with domain name and not success.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Seems like your websocket server is only bound the loopback interface. How did you start the websocket server? Set `0.0.0.0` as host/ip instead of `127.0.0.1` How did you configure the firewall? Add some details

Comment: port 6001 added by this command: sudo ufw allow 6001/tcp

Comment: and checked with 0.0.0.0 as server ip but the result was the same as 127.0.0.1

Comment: Answer all questions if you expect help. `How did you start the websocket server?` Edit your question and add details! Take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try `Ratchet\App("0.0.0.0", 6001);` instead of `Ratchet\App('localhost', 6001);` "localhost" resolves to "127.0.0.1", which is your loopback interface, ergo no request to your external/ip interface can be handeld because no network socked is bound to it.

Comment: tried and no success  . is it possible to be firewall issue ?

Comment: netstat command response  :      
     
`tcp        0       0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      379646/php`